# When is the internal operator being used and when the external

Tags: c++

Let's say I have defined a class with an internal `+` operator and also an external `+` operator;

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass operator +();
};

MyClass operator +(const MyClass& a);
```

If in my main program I call

```
MyClass a;
MyClass b = +a;
```

What is being called, this (internal):

```
a.operator +()
```

or this (external)?:

```
operator +(a)
```

The same question for binary operators.

Comment: Did you try `std::cout << "internal\n";` in the internal, and `"external\n"` in the external?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The member function is chosen: it can bind directly to the expression `a`, while the non-member function needs to convert `MyClass` to `const MyClass` before binding to the reference parameter. So calling the member involves a better conversion sequence, making that the best overload.

If you removed `const` from the non-member, or added `const` to the member, then both would be equally viable; you should get an error saying that the overload is ambiguous.

Comment: how could I add `const` to the member? do you mean it should return a `const MyClass` to be equal to the external operator?

Comment: @dabadaba: The usual way: `MyClass operator +() const;`

Comment: oh ok a constant method. In that case the one used is the external one. Interesting. However I get the warning you pointed out. If I remove `const` from the external operator's argument, I get an error instead of a warning. But if I declare the member operator as const, then the external operator is used. I don't get it.

Comment: @dabadaba: If I declare both (or neither) as `const`, then I get an error since it's ambiguous: http://ideone.com/iC4gT1. If you remove `const` from the non-member, and add it to the member, then the non-member becomes the better overload, since it no longer requires a conversion while the member now does.

Answer (score 2):

By fixing some ambiguities in the code, and doing some printing, the following code will give the answer `Internal operator`.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass operator+() {
        std::cout << "Internal operator." << std::endl;
        return *this;
    };
};

MyClass operator+(const MyClass& a) {
    std::cout << "External operator" << std::endl;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    MyClass a, b;
    b = +a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. (however, the purpose was just to show which function was called, not to actually use the answer. ).

Comment: it would be awesome an explanation of why the internal operator is being used and not the external and also what would be the case where the external was used and not the internal. I could have easily printed the results and reach the same conclussion, but the interesting thing is giving a reason.

Comment: @dabadaba: See my answer. One involves a conversion to `const` and one doesn't, making it a better overload.

Answer (score 0):

The internal operator is used because you cannot overload an operator with the same arguments once it already exists: you cannot define a + operator for strings that does something crazy because there already is one that concatenates them. That's the same case. You have a + operator defined inside the class, so the identical one( as function prototype ) becomes useless.

Comment: No, you can declare both member and non-member candidates, and either might be chosen depending on the operand type. (It's generally a bad idea, but not something you can't do).

Comment: But I vas talking about the case when the prototypes( the return type, name and arguments ) are the same. Then, the non-member candidate is useless because it is never called.

Comment: But that's not the case here. They have different parameter types (`MyClass` vs. `const MyClass`), so either could be chosen depending on the operand types. If they were the same, then the overload would be ambiguous, giving an error.

Comment: Sorry. I did't see it. Usually the operator+ method is declared as const and I guess I just got used to seeing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little test myself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;

MyClass operator +(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{ cout << "external" << endl; return a; }

int main() {
    MyClass foo, bar;
    foo + bar;
    return 0;
}

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& a) { cout << "internal" << endl; return a; }
};
```

The output of the program was "internal".
My conclusion is that if there is an internal operator that fits the operation it will be the one taken. I can't see a way to make the external one to be taken if the internal fits better. But I must point out that I only did a little test and haven't learned somewhere that this is the 100% answer.